# How does the blinding become perfect in Ferguson's Randomized Blind Signature Scheme

Tags: rsa, signature

[image]

Trying to figure out how the scheme works I came across the last paragraph of the page. As stated, for any possible additional factor we multiply by the specified power v of the element g. How did this "possible factor" showed up? Even so, why multiplying with the specified power v of g solves the appearance of such factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible factor shows up when $e$ is calculated and transmitted. Although the specifications states
$$e\leftarrow f(a_1a_2)-\sigma$$
because $f(a_1a_2)$ and $\sigma$ are considered as elements of $\mathbb Z_v$ the computation is implicitly performed modulo $v$ and so might be rendered in C for example as

```
e = (f(a1*a2)-sigma)%v
```

If $0\le f(a_1,a_2)<v$ and $0\le\sigma<v$ there are two possibilities if we instead consider $e$, $f$ and $\sigma$ as integers: either
$$e=f(a_1,a_2)-\sigma$$
or
$$e=f(a_1,a_2)-\sigma+v.$$
It is the $v$ in this second expression which creates the possible factor when $g^e$ is computed by the bank. If we run through the protocol as written in the first case, everything follows, becausethe value $\overline A$ computed by the Bank satisfies
$$\overline A^{1/v}=\gamma (a_1a_2)^{1/v}g^{f(a_1a_2)/v}$$
but in the second case we see that
$$\overline A^{1/v}=\gamma (a_1a_2)^{1/v}g^{1+f(a_1a_2)/v}$$
and so when $S$ is checked the equation does not hold. Instead the value of $S$ computed would be $ag^{f(a)+1}$, but by multiplying $S$ by $g^{-1}$ equality is attained. Note that

```
(f(a1*a2)-sigma)/v
```

is equal to zero in the first case and minus one in the second.

Comment: Numbers that belong in $Z_{n}$ might be initially considered positive integers instead of congruence classes. For example $0\le a < n$ and $0\le b < n$, such that $a+b \in Z$, instead of $a = [k]_{n}$ and $b = [l]_{n}$ for $k,l \in Z$. The modulo operation is used only when specified and not throughout the context. That means that $a+b$ might satisfy $a+b < -n$. The notation ($a$ div $b$) is used in the scheme instead of the  floor division operator (//) in programming languages.